# Linq to XML querying

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

If I have an xml file that looks like what I have below, is it possible to  find specific elements by name and modify their values?

For example, given my tree structure is there a way to do something like:

```
string xml = @"<root>  
      <para>  
            <r>  
              <s>
                27
              </s >
              <t size = 'M'>
                34
              </t >
              <u>
                <v>
                    65
                </v>
              </u>
            </r>  
            <r>  
            <u>
                <v>
                    65
                </v>
            </u>
            </r>  
            <r>  
                <t>bla</t>  
            </r>  
      </para>  
    </root>"

XElement doc = XElement.Parse(xml);

var result = doc.Elements("v")
           .ToList();

foreach (var el in result)
{
    el.value = "Something";
}

//and then save the modified tree
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SetValue to update the element. In your case, you need to update your query as well to get the "v" elements.

```
XElement doc = XElement.Parse(xml);

var result = doc.Descendants("v");

foreach (XElement item in result)
{

    item.SetValue("New Value");
}
var newXml = doc.ToString();
```

Output

```
<root>
  <para>
    <r>
      <s>
                27
              </s>
      <t size="M">
                34
              </t>
      <u>
        <v>New Value</v>
      </u>
    </r>
    <r>
      <u>
        <v>New Value</v>
      </u>
    </r>
    <r>
      <t>bla</t>
    </r>
  </para>
</root>
```

Comment: I must mention that I do not necessarily know the tree structure ahead of time.  That's why I'm wondering if there is a way to get an element directly by name.